# Importing a table from CSV in a schema takes too time in mysql WorkBench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, sql-insert

I am trying to import a CSV with 66K rows, it takes too time when trying to import in table to a schema using workbench using option 'Table data import wizard'.
Please help, is this related to RAM usage, is it creating any bottleneck for performance.

This is mysql workbench 8.0

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option would be to try and import the file directly from MySQL using [the `LOAD DATA INFILE` Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html). You first need to manually create the structure of the table that you want to feed, and then you can use a command like :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/MyDocuments/MyFile.csv' INTO TABLE my_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINE -- if the first CSV row contains headers
```